# Serialize programmatic CSS style sheets (stylesheets that use CSSOM API)?

Tags: javascript, css, css-in-js, cssom

You can use `document.documentElement.outerHTML` in order to serialize a document to a HTML string.

However, if we paste the result into a file and try to render it as HTML, it will not be always be faithful to the original display (ignoring truly dynamic elements like `canvas`). Why? Any website that uses CSS in JS will have empty style tags that effect the styling of the web-page. These stylesheets are manipulated using the [CSSOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model).

I want to serialize web-pages while also including stylesheets that are programatically manipulated. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you put up a small example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```js
export function getCSSOMStyles(): string {
  const { styleSheets } = document;
  const CSSOMSheets = Array.from(styleSheets).filter((sheet) => {
    const hasHref = Boolean(sheet.href);
    //@ts-expect-error - too hard to Typescriptify
    const hasStylesInDOM = (sheet.ownerNode?.innerText?.length || 0) > 0;
    return sheet.cssRules && !hasHref! && !hasStylesInDOM;
  });

  const CSSOMStylesText = CSSOMSheets.map((sheet) =>
    Array.from(sheet.cssRules)
      .map((rule) => rule.cssText)
      .join("")
  ).join("");
  return CSSOMStylesText;
}

export const injectCSSOMStyles = (document: Document) => {
  const styles = getCSSOMStyles();
  if (styles.length === 0) return;

  const styleSheet = document.createElement("style");
  // TODO: Why is this deprecated?
  styleSheet.type = "text/css";
  const stylesText = document.createTextNode(getCSSOMStyles());
  styleSheet.appendChild(stylesText);
  document.head.appendChild(styleSheet);
};

export const serializeCSSInJSStyles = injectCSSOMStyles;
```